# Create a MultiIndex Pandas DataFrame for term counting and frequency tracking

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am doing machine learning using a Word2Vec-like approach on an extremely large corpus on non-human language utterances. I want to collect all pairs of words into a pairs dataframe indexed by the word pairs (u, and v) and containing the following columns: id, freq, first_seen, last_seen. Ids must be unique, have no gaps, and be numbered from 0 until len(dataframe)-1. I am building this dataframe as I traverse a large corpus. Here's what it looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

idx0 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(combinations('the quick brown fox jumps over'.split(),2)))
idx0.names = ['u','v']
idx1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(combinations('fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split(),2)))
idx1.names = ['u','v']
df0 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'id' : range(len(idx0)),
        'freq' : [1]*len(idx0),
        'first_seen' : [0]*len(idx0),
        'last_seen' : [1]*len(idx0),
    },
    index=idx0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        'id' : range(len(idx0),len(idx0)+len(idx1)),
        'freq' : [1]*len(idx1),
        'first_seen' : [1]*len(idx1),
        'last_seen' : [2]*len(idx1),
    },
    index=idx1)
```

df0 looks like:

```
             id  freq  first_seen  last_seen
u     v                                     
the   quick   0     1           0          1
      brown   1     1           0          1
      fox     2     1           0          1
      jumps   3     1           0          1
      over    4     1           0          1
quick brown   5     1           0          1
      fox     6     1           0          1
      jumps   7     1           0          1
      over    8     1           0          1
brown fox     9     1           0          1
      jumps  10     1           0          1
      over   11     1           0          1
fox   jumps  12     2           0          2
      over   13     2           0          2
jumps over   14     2           0          2
```

df1 looks like:

```
             id  freq  first_seen  last_seen
u     v                                     
fox   jumps  15     1           1          2
      over   16     1           1          2
      the    17     1           1          2
      lazy   18     1           1          2
      dog    19     1           1          2
jumps over   20     1           1          2
      the    21     1           1          2
      lazy   22     1           1          2
      dog    23     1           1          2
over  the    24     1           1          2
      lazy   25     1           1          2
      dog    26     1           1          2
the   lazy   27     1           1          2
      dog    28     1           1          2
lazy  dog    29     1           1          2
```

So far so good. Then I want to merge the two and use the meerge as a template for accumulating totals and calculating time stamps in the first_seen, last_seen columns:

```
dfm = df0.merge(df1,how='outer',indicator=True,left_on=('u','v'),right_on=('u','v'))
gb = dfm.groupby('_merge')

for u,v in gb.get_group('both').index:
    df0.loc[(u,v),'freq'] += df1.loc[(u,v),'freq']
    df0.loc[(u,v),'last_seen'] = df1.loc[(u,v),'last_seen']

additions = []
for u,v in gb.get_group('right_only').index:
    additions.append((u,v))
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(additions)

newdf = pd.concat([df0,df1.loc(axis=0)[midx]])
```

newdf becomes:

```
             id  freq  first_seen  last_seen
u     v                                     
the   quick   0     1           0          1
      brown   1     1           0          1
      fox     2     1           0          1
      jumps   3     1           0          1
      over    4     1           0          1
quick brown   5     1           0          1
      fox     6     1           0          1
      jumps   7     1           0          1
      over    8     1           0          1
brown fox     9     1           0          1
      jumps  10     1           0          1
      over   11     1           0          1
fox   jumps  12     2           0          2
      over   13     2           0          2
jumps over   14     2           0          2
fox   the    17     1           1          2
      lazy   18     1           1          2
      dog    19     1           1          2
jumps the    21     1           1          2
      lazy   22     1           1          2
      dog    23     1           1          2
over  the    24     1           1          2
      lazy   25     1           1          2
      dog    26     1           1          2
the   lazy   27     1           1          2
      dog    28     1           1          2
lazy  dog    29     1           1          2
```

which is close, but there's problems:

1. Every pair (u,v) should be sequentially numbered. Because (fox,jumps) was id=12 in df0 and id=15 in df1, the frequencies were properly added and the last_seen was updated, but now we are missing id=15, #16, and #20 in newdf.
2. Every pair must occur exactly once in the dataframe. I have no assurance that my method is guaranteeing this.
3. This seems like a wildly inefficient way to update a dataframe 30 million times or so.

Seems the best way to fix the first problem is to renumber the end of newdf['id']:

```
ser = newdf['id']
ser.iloc[-12:] = range(len(df0),len(df0)+len(gb.get_group('right_only')))
newdf['id'] = ser
```

There ought to be a cleaner, more pythonic, more "pandastic" way of doing this. But all my searching of the documentation hasn't found a better way. It feels like .agg() and .unique() should be in my solution somewhere, too.

I welcome any thoughts or clarifications on the matter.

Thanks,
Glenn

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

Taking the max of last seen, sum of freq, and min of first seen, then just renumber the ids sequentially?

```
dfm['last_seen'] = dfm[['last_seen_x','last_seen_y']].max(1)
dfm['freq'] = dfm[['freq_x','freq_y']].sum(1)
dfm['first_seen'] = dfm[['first_seen_x','first_seen_y']].min(1)
dfm['id'] = list(range(len(dfm)))

dfm[['id','freq','first_seen','last_seen']]
```

Output

```
             id  freq  first_seen  last_seen
u     v                                     
the   quick   0   1.0         0.0        1.0
      brown   1   1.0         0.0        1.0
      fox     2   1.0         0.0        1.0
      jumps   3   1.0         0.0        1.0
      over    4   1.0         0.0        1.0
quick brown   5   1.0         0.0        1.0
      fox     6   1.0         0.0        1.0
      jumps   7   1.0         0.0        1.0
      over    8   1.0         0.0        1.0
brown fox     9   1.0         0.0        1.0
      jumps  10   1.0         0.0        1.0
      over   11   1.0         0.0        1.0
fox   jumps  12   2.0         0.0        2.0
      over   13   2.0         0.0        2.0
jumps over   14   2.0         0.0        2.0
fox   the    15   1.0         1.0        2.0
      lazy   16   1.0         1.0        2.0
      dog    17   1.0         1.0        2.0
jumps the    18   1.0         1.0        2.0
      lazy   19   1.0         1.0        2.0
      dog    20   1.0         1.0        2.0
over  the    21   1.0         1.0        2.0
      lazy   22   1.0         1.0        2.0
      dog    23   1.0         1.0        2.0
the   lazy   24   1.0         1.0        2.0
      dog    25   1.0         1.0        2.0
lazy  dog    26   1.0         1.0        2.0
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris, almost. Except this is a streaming application, and the ids that have previously been assigned must not be changed, however, no ids can be skipped and none may be duplicated. Thanks for the first and last seen solution. I think that will work. It just seems like column-wise calculations should be something that merge could do itself. Sigh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was looking for is something like this:

```
df = df.groupby(['u','v']).agg({'id':'first','first_seen':'first','last_seen':'last','freq':'sum'})
```

The result still requires some messing with, but this is *so* much simpler than the original.